# Facebook proxy web application - Is it good architecture/design?

Tags: java, facebook, architecture

I am trying to build a java web application, which is a facebook app. Say this app is "Test App" on facebook and it is hosted and served from "xyz.com". Now, I would like to make this java app running at xyz.com - a little generic - The idea would be to create **N** apps "Test App1" (hosted at abc.com) , "Test App2" (hosted at efg.com) , and so on (kind of like a service), use just this one webapp at xyz.com to serve the GUI for each of these apps. So, for every incoming request on any of the fb apps, xyz.com webapp would identify which app needs to be served and open a GET request to it, get the html response from it, include it as part of its own html response. In short, this  is how it is going to look like:

*User of "Test App1" -> iframe tries to load xyz.com -> servlet code on xyz.com app opens a HTTP GET request to abc.com -> Gets response -> includes it in its own reponse -> sends response.*

Does this make sense? Is this a good design at all? I have a feeling that I am trying to make it look like a fake portal, with xyz.com opening up a new HTTP Get for every incoming request, I think it will fail miserably when it has to scale. What is the best way to design this kind of a proxy web app - a) for flexibility (to serve more apps) b) for scalability.

Comment: one more question - is this even legal by facebook T&C?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is not architectural issue. Try to switch the point of view on the problem, for me it's about deployment.

You've designed an application and you want run it on different domains, is this right?

If true, you've at least these two options:

- Act on web server configuration (if you decide for **housing** or you deploy in your organization).
- Act on configuration provided by your service host (if you decide for **hosting**).

About the legal question, sorry, I can't help you; but I can suggest to search facebook partnership guidelines (or try to ask to a facebook salesman).

Comment: architectural issue from the view point of scalability. If a web application acts like a proxy - it might not scale?

Comment: @Jay, about performance and scalability it's hard to say without knowledge of what your application does. Yes, we know it use the facebook WS, but what else, DB access (or other kind of storage)? My suggestion is to keep it simple and rely on configuration way (if this is feasible for the project, I don't know all details).

Comment: ok.. its not about scalability in general - its about a specific activity - opening up connections to other sites (acting like a proxy server). How many connections can I open? how much is too much? how will I scale thousands of users?